# In an Outlook 2013 C# VSTO project, why does the Explorer SelectionChange event fire twice

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

In my Outlook 2013 C# VSTO project I've noticed that the Explorer SelectionChange event is firing twice. I thought it must be due to a bug in my code (like hooking the event handler up twice), but I couldn't find any such bugs.

So I went back to basics and created a little VSTO Outlook 2013 Addin test project, and the same thing happens there too. The Explorer SelectionChange event is fired twice.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Explorer _activeExplorer;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _activeExplorer = Application.Explorers[1];

        _activeExplorer.SelectionChange += _activeExplorer_SelectionChange;
    }

    private void _activeExplorer_SelectionChange()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("_activeExplorer_SelectionChange : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I can code around this, but surely the SelectionChange event shouldn't be firing twice.

Any ideas why the SelectionChange event is firing twice?
And what can I do to make it fire only once (other than writing my own code to check if the selection has changed)?

Comment: How did you determine that it fires twice? Did you make sure Outlook is closed between debugging sessions? You don't unsubscribe during Shutdown so you could be subscribing twice to the same explorer instance during debugging

Comment: I don't think you'll get a direct answer to this one. It *does* fire twice (as everyone who has worked with this event can confirm), but I doubt you'll get an official explanation as to why. That "check if selection has changed" workaround is part of *every* time intensive SelectionChange event handler I've seen.

Comment: How many Explorer windows do you have opened? Try to use the ActiveExplorer method instead of indexer. Does it help? Finally, do you have any other add-ins installed for Outlook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off the **Reading Pane** in Outlook:

[image]

After you turn it off you will get only event at a time.

Comment: Turned the Reading Pane off, and only 1 SelectionChange event was fired. Mystery solved. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, butt this is not a real solution to the problem. You cannot enforce the user to close is Reading Pane - that's an absolute comfort feature for Outlook users. :|

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += activeExplorer_SelectionChange;
}
private void activeExplorer_SelectionChange()
{
    Selection selection = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    if (selection != null && selection.Count == 1 && selection[1] is MailItem)
    {
        MailItem selectedMail = selection[1] as MailItem;
        selectedMail.Read += SelectedMail_Read;
    }
}

private void SelectedMail_Read()
{
     Selection selection = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
     MailItem selectedMail = selection[1] as MailItem;
     ...
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.